# How to let a java program comunicate with a different java program

Tags: java, sockets, minecraft, bungeecord

I am trying to build a system that loadbalances minecraft players across multiple servers and creates new minecraft servers. I made a plugin to loadbalance players and it works like a charm. But now I want to make a system that creates new servers based on the data it receives from the plugin.

This system is completely seperate from the plugin. But how do I make it so the plugin sends some sort of command to the server system so it knows to create a new server. I have looked into Sockets but was wondering if this is the best solution. Maybe a Rest api will work aswell?

Comment: Socket, rest api, messaging or distributed caching utility hazelcast can be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the best solution is sockets based on your own protocol, it will be much more productive, than http or something else.
I can suggest using this lightweight socket library written by me -
[Sonder](https://github.com/tix320/sonder).
It's working directly on sockets using nio.

Comment: You can't use raw sockets in Java. Do you mean TCP sockets?

Comment: Yes. The word 'raw' there is implied low level.

Comment: Don't misuse standard terminology. 'Raw socket' means SOCK_RAW, and you can't do that in Java.

Answer (score -2):

You could solve this by having one java program write to a .txt file and another program read the line then delete the command using java.io.FileWriter and java.util.Scanner. I have a github project that does this here:

> https://github.com/DPS100/Diego-s-Project-Euler/blob/master/Main.java

Comment: This solution is full of race conditions. There are far better options.